# 302 status upon login form submission to login_check route

Tags: symfony

Good evening,

I recently installed symfony3, meaning I created my user entity, loaded user fixtures, set up firewall/provider/form_login entries in the security configuration file, as well as implementing a security controller to handle the /login route.

I'm now stuck at trying to log in the application using the authentication mechanism embeded with SF.

When hitting `/`, I get redirected to `/login`and the login form is being rendered as expected. But upon submission (to `/login_check`) via post method, SF replies with a 302 and redirects me back to the login form.

`/login_check` route is supposed to be handled by SF right ? So I expected some exception to arise, but none did though.

Seams to be a firewall issue as enlightened in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088982/symfony2-6-login-check-goes-to-error-302-and-application-doesnt-connect), but it did not help me.

My security conf file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12
    providers:
        ent_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern:   ^/(login|register|resetting)$
            security: false
            anonymous: ~
        app:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: false
            provider: ent_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
```

Can someone please help me pointing out what's wrong with my security configuration ? (Or anything else ...)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Symfony 3.1.0-DEV**

I can garantee that you can define both «/login» & «login_check» routes as annotations in your SecurityController.

The only requirement is that:

- the `/login` url must be available anonymously, a special firewall can be created for this purpose
- whereas `/login_check` has to be protected by the secured firewall

so here is my configuration

```
# app/config/routing.yml
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
# Security
logout:
    path: /logout
```

My security.conf

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        pattern:   ^/login$
        anonymous: ~
    secured:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: false
        provider: ent_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /login
```

Both login and login_check routes can then be declared as annotations but only the loginAction has to be implemented inside your controller (as stated in the documentation)

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render(
        'AppBundle::security/login.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error
        )
    );
}

/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
 */
public function loginCheckAction()
{
    // this controller will not be executed,
    // as the route is handled by the Security system
    throw new \Exception('Which means that this Exception will not be raised anytime soon …');
}
```

I spent days trying to figure out those problems, I hope this will save time for some of you struggling as I did `:o`

Comment: I got the same problem on Symfony 4.2. ¿Are there any updates?

Answer (score 0):

The /login_check route is not fully handled by SF. You must specify this route:

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php

// ...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login_route")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
     */
    public function loginCheckAction()
    {
        // this controller will not be executed,
        // as the route is handled by the Security system
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html).

Comment: Sure, this is what I did already. We are responsible for the loginAction implementation but not loginCheckAction. I just added a `throw ...Exception` statement inside loginCheckAction function to emphasis a wrong configuration if SF ends up here. Does my security config file look ok to you ?